# Surface area of smooth manifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

Let $D$ be a simply connected bounded domain in $\mathbb R^n$ and assume that its boundary $\partial D$, is a $\textit{smooth}$ closed manifold. Is the following true?
$$\int_{\partial D\cap{B_r(x)}}\frac{ds_y}{\|x-y\|^{n-2}}=\text{O}(\frac{r^{n-1}}{r^{n-2}})=\text{O}(r)$$ 
as $r\to 0$, where $B_r(x)=\{t:|t-x|<r\}$ and $ds$ denotes the surface area.

Comment: Is $\Omega$ the same as $D$?

Comment: @JackLee yeah.corrected it